# How to apply perspective transform to Bezier curve?

Tags: graphics, geometry, 2d, bezier, perspectivecamera

Should I apply transform to Bezier control points only? Will this be correct?

Or should I add some corrections?

Transform is 2D->2D with matrix

```
a b c 
d e f
g h 1
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. You can apply affine transform to Bezier control points and obtain new Bezier curve.

But perspective transformation transforms polynomial curve (traditional Bezier) into rational curve. It may be described by rational Bezier curve or NURBS ([short reference p.111](http://ansatte.hin.no/ltd/Wednesday_Week_1/GeoMod1/Day%203/3.pdf))

So it is possible to represent usual Bezier curve as rational curve (it is always possible), apply persp. transform to control points of rational curve (using weights in homogeneous form), and draw new rational curve.

Comment: When you apply perspective transform, then transformed curves will no longer Bezier curves

Comment: Okay, it is no more Bezier curve anymore. But how to obtain data of what it is?